# Disable Chrome Devtools Element Panel Tickertape AutoScroll

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Does anyone know of a way to stop this part of the dev tools from slowly auto-scrolling when you are deep in the element tree?

The constant movement is distracting sometimes; I would rather it not start scrolling or just jump to the end.

[image: Chrome DevTools Ticker Tape]

Comment: You'll have to make a custom devtools theme extension and disable the animation. Alternatively, suggest disabling it on https://crbug.com.